# Data from detected table

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I have a use case to extract data from invoices and receipts. These would be in image format.

Since these contain table also (with or without borders), I have detected the table and now I want to extract data from the detected table.
(I have got the mask with the help of some pre processing.)

I want to extract the table data using the mask I got.

**Image:** [image]

**Mask:** [image: mask]

[Dilated image of original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AngZV.png)

Comment: Dilate the image with a horizontal kernel (like a 1*5 kernel) to stick the letters of each part together. Then use connected components method to extract them and use them as a mask to separate each field of a table. After that you do OCR on them.

Comment: @Meisam, thanks for your reply.
As you said, I have dilated the original image with a horizontal kernel. Now I am able to stick the letters. (Have edited the question to add dilated image)

However, I am not sure how to use **connected components method**.
I have googled but could not find the application that suits me.

(PS: Sorry if I am asking basic questions and sounding stupid. I have just started working with OpenCV and still learning :)  )

Comment: In python :  cv2.connectedComponents(img). You could also use  cv2.findContour command instead. When you got the objects from images, remove the lines based on their size.

Comment: I think you can extract these data from the table without OpenCV, after text and position retrieved bt tesseract.